# Install Oracle JRE 1.6 on JDK 1.5

Tags: java

I have Oracle JDK and JRE 1.5 installed  ubuntu LTS. I want to keep JDK 1.5 and install Oracle JRE as 1.6. please let me know the steps or any clear source where I can get this done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice way to do this is by using the [webupd8 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
```

To switch which version is used when you type `java` (or `javac` etc..) use `sudo update-alternatives --config java` (or javac of course)